# IBM's UML Sequence Example: why lack of activation for lifeline

Tags: uml, sequence, activation

I've found [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/the-sequence-diagram/) on sequence diagrams very helpful but I'm having trouble understanding a couple of things in diagram 11:
[image]

1. Why is the customer lifeline not activated after sending the `WithdrawCash` message?  My understanding is that an object awaiting a response should be activated.
2. Why isn't the `cash` return message included in the `opt [balance > amount]`?
   Wouldn't this imply that the customer gets cash even in case the conditions aren't met, since `cash` is sent regardless (outside) of the opt?

Answer (score 0):

1. I haven't seen the notation. But I'd simply assume that the lifetime of the caller is negligible. When browsing the specs I found a similar notation on p. 585 where there is just the dashed line:

[image]

2. The `opt` fragment  (that rectangle area) says that the contents inside is only executed optional. So the `debit` message is only sent when `balance > amount` (the guard in square brackets). The example is inaccurate as it does not handle the "no cash returned" path (some error handling).